# How can I clear widget in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, widget, ids

I am making a selection app. I am using a spinner for multiple choises. After spinner selection I want to add 3 different buttons, which are related to spinner selection. In every selection in spinner those old buttons replace with new ones.

So far I can add different buttons after every selection. However, the buttons are keep adding. I need to clear the old buttons first after every spinner selection.

My class, which contains buttons is "ModelSpecifications".

Long story short, there is something wrong in clear_widgets(). It cant reach "ModelSpecifications".

Here is my main.py;

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from collections import OrderedDict

data1=["mother","father","son"]
data2=["uncle","aunt","grandfather"]
data3=["jack","mike","simon"]
data4=["1898","1975","1985","1885"]

class MainWidget(Widget):

    an0=tuple(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data1)))
    cal5= ObjectProperty()

    def btn10(self,text):

    #----------here is the part I want to clear the buttons first:

        #ModelSpecifications.clear_widgets(ModelSpecifications)

        # or

        #self.ids["anss"].clear_widgets()

        # after that I will add new buttons:
    
        self.cal5 =ModelSpecifications()


        a=data2
        b=data3
        c=data4

        mi=[]
        n=0

        while n < len(a):
            aba=(str(a[n])+"\n"+str(b[n])+"\n"+str(c[n]))
            mi.append(aba)
            n+=1

        for i in mi:
            self.b1=Button(text=str(i),size_hint=(1,None),height="100dp")
            self.cal5.add_widget(self.b1)
        self.ids.scd.add_widget(self.cal5, index=3) #here id.scd is the class that ModelSpecifications class is added. And it works fine.

class SecondPage(ScrollView):
    pass

class ModelSpecifications(BoxLayout): #this is the class I want add after my spinner selection 
    pass

class Calculation(GridLayout):
    pass   

class MyApp(App):
    pass

MyApp().run()
```

And here is my.kv ;

```
MainWidget:
<MainWidget>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: scmanager
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            id: scndpage
            name: "second"
            SecondPage:
                Calculation:
                    id:scd            
                    cols:1 
                    height: self.minimum_height 
                    row_default_height: "70dp"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    spacing:"10dp"
                    canvas.before:
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    BoxLayout:

                        size_hint: 1, None
                        height: "50dp"
                        
                        pading:"10dp"
                        spacing:"10dp"
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: "horizontal"
                            Label:
                                text:"Name:"
                                color: 0,0,0,1
                            TextInput:
                                text:"---"
                                color: 0,0,0,1
                            Label:
                                text:"Surname:"
                                color: 0,0,0,1
                            TextInput:
                                text:"-----"
                                color: 0,0,0,1
                    BoxLayout:
                        id:scdd
                        size_hint: 1, 1
                        height: "100dp"
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        BoxLayout:
                            size_hint: 1, None
                            height: "50dp"
                            orientation: "horizontal"
                            Label:
                                text: " Sellection:"
                                color: 0,0,0,1
                            Spinner:
                                text: 'Home'
                                values: root.an0
                                on_text: app.root.btn10(self.text)                                       
                    
                    Button:
                        text:" Calculate"

                    Button:
                        text:"Sellect"
                    
                    Button:
                        text:"Back"

    
<ModelSpecifications>:      
    id:anss                 #HERE IS MY CLASS THAT I WANT TO CLEAR AND ADD AFTER EVERY SPINNER SELECTION
    pading:"10dp"
    spacing:"10dp"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "100dp"
    orientation: "horizontal"
```

When you run this code sellect something in spinner. You will see in every selection, app keeps add more buttons;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `btn10()` method, just add:

```
    if self.cal5:
        self.cal5.parent.remove_widget(self.cal5)
```

before the line:

```
    self.cal5 = ModelSpecifications()
```

Comment: Thank you very much John. It is so much helpfull.